# insert from form submission to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

My html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Total Duration in Second</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="duration" name="total_duration">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Description Duration</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="duration" name="desc_duration">
                            </div>
```

---

the php:

```
<?php

                    include('lib/conn_sqli.php');
                    include ('lib/conn.php');
                    $total_duration = $_POST['total_duration'];
                    $desc_duration = $_POST['desc_duration'];



                    $sql = "INSERT INTO vote.duration (id_duration, total_duration, desc_duration) VALUES (null, $total_duration, $desc_duration)";
                    mysql_query($sql);
                    if ($sql){
                        echo ("succeed");
                    }
                    ?>
```

---

The conn_sqli.php:

```
<?php
    // connect database -------------------------------------------->
    $db = new mysqli ( "localhost" , "abc" , "123" , "vote" );
    echo $db->connect_errno?'Connection failed : '.$db->connect_error:'';
    //<--------------------------------------------------------------
    ?>
```

---

The conn.php:

```
<?php
$db_host    = "localhost";
$db_user    = "abc";
$db_pass    = "123";
$db_name    = "vote";
$konek  = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name) or die ("Gagal Koneksi ke Server");
mysql_select_db($db_name, $konek) or die ("Gagal Mengaktifkan Database".mysql_error());
?>
```

---

The code simply doesn't work. The php will echo "Succeed", but no data is inserted. I know this is so simple but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: bad cobination of mysql_* and mysqli_*.

Answer (score 0):

### Notes:

- Don't combine the [deprecated `mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) API
- Use at least `*_real_escape_string()` function before binding a raw data to your query
- Use a single tick (`'`) to bind variables to your query, better yet, use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- Do [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Here's a simple example of your code in prepared statement (*assuming that id_duration column is your primary key and in auto-increment*):

```
<?php

    include('lib/conn_sqli.php');
    // include ('lib/conn.php'); COMMENT THIS OUT OR REMOVE THIS
    $total_duration = $_POST['total_duration'];
    $desc_duration = $_POST['desc_duration'];

    if($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO duration (total_duration, desc_duration) VALUES (?, ?)")){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $total_duration, $desc_duration);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo ("succeed");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are totally in the wrong way.
The HTML Form:

```
    <form method="post" action="insert.php">
       <label for="total_duration">Total Duration in Second</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_duration" name="total_duration">
        <label for="desc_duration">Description Duration</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc_duration" name="desc_duration">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

The insert to the database, let me say it insert.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$total_duration = $_POST['total_duration'];
$desc_duration = $_POST['desc_duration'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO vote.duration(total_duration, desc_duration) VALUES ($total_duration, $desc_duration)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Why are you setting `NULL` the `id_duration`? Make it `AutoIncrement` if you don't want to `insert` value every time.

Comment: Two `VALUES()`? And what is up with the variables with no `$` before them? Like `total_duration = $_POST['total_duration'];`

Comment: Oh thanks for mentioning that! It was just a bit of rush when i was typping and the awkard thing came out :P I edited, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem.